# WSO2 Carbon: Error deleting a tenant

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2

I'm trying to delete a tenant created using the TenantMgtAdminServiceStub. In the carbon logs it shows the following:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-07 23:52:10,645]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-07 23:52:10,645-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-07 23:52:10,784]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-04-07 23:52:10,784-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-07 23:52:10,866]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService} -  Starting Tenant Deletion process... {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-07 23:52:11,150] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService} -  Error in notifying tenant addition. {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService}
org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.exception.StratosException: Error occurred while revoking the access tokens in tenant 10
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.util.TenantMgtUtil.triggerPreTenantDelete(TenantMgtUtil.java:118)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.notifyTenantDeletion(TenantMgtAdminService.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.deleteTenant(TenantMgtAdminService.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        ...
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error occurred while retrieving 'ACTIVE or EXPIRED' access tokens for user  tenant id : 10
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1192)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:87)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ambiguous column name "USER_DOMAIN"; SQL statement:
SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE, TOKEN_SCOPE, ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID, AUTHZ_USER, USER_DOMAIN, CONSUMER_KEY FROM (SELECT AUTHZ_USER, USER_DOMAIN, CONSUMER_KEY_ID, TOKEN_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN WHERE TENANT_ID=? AND (TOKEN_STATE='ACTIVE' OR TOKEN_STATE='EXPIRED')) ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE JOIN IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS ON ID = CONSUMER_KEY_ID LEFT JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE ON ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID = IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE.TOKEN_ID [90059-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumn(ExpressionColumn.java:105)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumns(ExpressionColumn.java:82)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.init(Select.java:710)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1410)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:392)
        ...
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1149)
        ... 60 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-07 23:52:11,159] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService} -  Error deleting tenant with domain: juan7.com and tenant id: 10. {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService}
java.lang.Exception: Error in notifying tenant addition.
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.notifyTenantDeletion(TenantMgtAdminService.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.deleteTenant(TenantMgtAdminService.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        ...
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.exception.StratosException: Error occurred while revoking the access tokens in tenant 10
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.util.TenantMgtUtil.triggerPreTenantDelete(TenantMgtUtil.java:118)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.notifyTenantDeletion(TenantMgtAdminService.java:123)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error occurred while retrieving 'ACTIVE or EXPIRED' access tokens for user  tenant id : 10
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1192)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.onPreDelete(OAuthTenantMgtListenerImpl.java:87)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ambiguous column name "USER_DOMAIN"; SQL statement:
SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE, TOKEN_SCOPE, ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID, AUTHZ_USER, USER_DOMAIN, CONSUMER_KEY FROM (SELECT AUTHZ_USER, USER_DOMAIN, CONSUMER_KEY_ID, TOKEN_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, VALIDITY_PERIOD, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, USER_TYPE FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN WHERE TENANT_ID=? AND (TOKEN_STATE='ACTIVE' OR TOKEN_STATE='EXPIRED')) ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE JOIN IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS ON ID = CONSUMER_KEY_ID LEFT JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE ON ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE.TOKEN_ID = IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE.TOKEN_ID [90059-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumn(ExpressionColumn.java:105)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumns(ExpressionColumn.java:82)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.init(Select.java:710)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1410)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:392)
        ...
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.getAccessTokensOfTenant(TokenMgtDAO.java:1149)
        ... 60 more
```

The code that I'm using to delete the tenant is pretty straightforward:

```
String cookie = getCookie();

TenantMgtAdminServiceStub tenantMgtStub = null;
String tenantMgtEndpoint = apiManagerConfiguration.getCarbonUrl() + "TenantMgtAdminService";
tenantMgtStub = new TenantMgtAdminServiceStub(tenantMgtEndpoint);

Options option = tenantMgtStub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
option.setManageSession(true);   
option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, cookie);

tenantMgtStub.deleteTenant(domain);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to deactivate the tenant and then delete the tenant

```
tenantMgtStub.deactivateTenant(domainName);
tenantMgtStub.deleteTenant(domainName);
```

Hope this will help